# i don't know how to change my `username`, how can i?

Tags: directory, users, home-directory, username

how do i change the username in Ubuntu?

How can i change the username that shows in login, terminal, home directory.
I wish to change that but i don't know how.
My current username is `vibuntu`, i want to change that to `stark` and the name on `/home/vibuntu` to `/home/stark`
Please someone respond if you know how to change this.

Comment: Thats a long process, the is no command for it ?

Comment: That’s the way … it’s a deep rooted issue by nature … better to do it, carefully, the right way and understand the complications … I advise against shortcuts or arbitrarily running scripts from the internet.

Comment: @Raffa: Which of the 11 answers in your link would you advise the OP to start with?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I don't and I wont  ... **"carefully"** means read the answers, the comments and check the votes on each answer and **"understand the complications"** then decide ... eight answers though :)